# Use icon fonts in xpages

Tags: fonts, twitter-bootstrap, icons, xpages, font-awesome

I want to use icon (awesome) fonts in my xpage. I downloaded it and put them into my webContent folder (as all my additional stuff. e.g. bootstrap). I modified the awesome.css as followed.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  src: url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot');
  src: url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('eot');
  src: url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff') format('woff');
  src: url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
  src: url('/font/fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

And put an  into my page.

```
<i class="icon-refresh"></i>
```

The result is. I see a placeholder for that icon-font in my page and two error messages in firebug.

"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http: // localhost/home.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff"
"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http: // localhost/home.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"

So loading the fonts doesn't work (the files are in that folder font and my other css and js files I am using, are loaded with the same method).
I use bootstrap and deactivated the icons for the download (but I had the same problem with the glyphs there).

So maybe someone have an idea.

Comment: Are you able to access the font file at the url http://localhost/home.nsf/xsp/.ibmmodres/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff? Could be xpages won't serve certain types of files (I'm not familiar with xpages) or that the relative path is wrong in your css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the first slash, that should do it.

Plan B: move the fonts into the resource directory (if you use the Java perspective you can create your font directory)

Comment: The fonts are located in the subdirectory font below webContent (as all the other ressources). But I downloaded an own created icon-font set from icomoon. Their css had the correct path as you sad, without leading slashes and it works. But if I change this at the awesome-font css. It still doesn't work. But I can live with the icomoon fonts. Still one minor issue. The ie-hack doesn't work. I think it's a problem with the # (maybe I will figure it out). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I found it to be a problem with my server (in this case the localhost) not having the .woff registered as a mime-type of application/octet-stream.  Once I registered it, I no longer had the 404 not found error.