# Font Awesome webfont.woff and webfont.ttf 404 Not Found

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I am getting 404 Not Found errors in my XPages app on the following items:

```
https://my.domain.com/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/responsive/dijit/dbootstrap-0.1.1/theme/dbootstrap/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff

https://my.domain.com/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/responsive/dijit/dbootstrap-0.1.1/theme/dbootstrap/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf
```

This XPages app uses a custom theme which extends `Bootstrap3_flat`. In the theme, Font Awesome is referenced by using:

```
<resource>
    <content-type>text/css</content-type>
    <href>https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css</href>
</resource>
```

The following links describe similar issues, but I'm not sure exactly how to resolve my specific situation:

- [Use icon fonts in xpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12917201/use-icon-fonts-in-xpages)
- ["NetworkError: 404 Not Found fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104736/networkerror-404-not-found-fontawesome-webfont-woffv-4-0-3)

Comment: Verify that you can see the file by pasting the href maxcdn url into a browser.  If it's not working then that is your issue.

Comment: Remember that fonts are bound to CORS ruling, so check how you're referencing to them (sometimes even referencing the same domain on https or without www detonates CORS issues).

Comment: I am using Font Awesome from the same CDN in an application and have no issue with loading the fonts from the CDN. I suggest that you check your bootstrap theme for local references to the font files

Comment: @RobMason - I am able to view the file when I copy the cdn URL into my browser.
@PerHenrikLausten - I searched my application for `webfont` which resulted in no matches. Is this what you were referring to when you mentioned font files?

Comment: @RyanBuening: I am referring to the 404 links such as /dbootstrap-0.1.1/theme/dbootstrap/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff. Search your theme files for this reference. One more thing: have you tried using Font Awesome works from the CDN. My bet is that it loads the font files correctly from the CDN but your theme just has direct (and wrong) links to the font files.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: My theme is not referencing any of those files. However, I'm extending the `Bootstrap3_flat` theme that is built in from IBM with the XPages Extension Library. I believe that is where those webfont links are coming from but I don't think I have any control over that?

I also think you are correct in that the font files are being loaded correctly from the CDN.

Comment: @PerHenrikLausten: Disregard. I figured out the issue. Will update with answer.

Comment: I have the same issue, but just want to mention if I untick the "Use runtime optimized Javascrtipt and CSS resources" the fonts are loaded properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with extending the `Bootstrap3_flat` theme. I changed this to extend `Bootstrap3_blank`. See IBM article here: https://wiki.openntf.org/display/EXTLIB/How+to+use+the+Bootstrap3_blank.theme+in+XPages

I also needed to copy the `dbootstrap.css` file and customize it to remove references to the webfont.woff and webfont.tff files.

After I did this the 404 errors went away.

Answer (score -2):

My fontawesome fonts worked great in VisualStudio 2015.  After publishing to my 3rd party webserver, the fonts could not be found (404 error).  I can't explain why VS2015 worked, but here is the solution for me:  The fontawesome fonts are in ~/content/fonts/fontawesome after publish, but they needed to be in ~/fonts/ so I just copied them there and the problem was solved.  Using F12 on the webbrowser showed the 404 error and showed where the browser looked for the .woff and .ttf fonts.

Comment: I'm not using Visual Studio. I'm using Domino Designer with XPages.

Comment: OK, but my solution doesn't care what development tool is used.  The solution points out that the ultimate location of fontawesome fonts ends up in wrong folder on the server.  So my suggestion is to see if the fontawesome fonts are in the correct folder.  If they are in wrong folder, then copying them to correct folder solved my problem and might solve yours.